# Check for validation errors in twig template

Tags: php, forms, symfony, twig

My project uses Symfony with Twig as template engine. I have an embedded form in which I do some validation. I want to show validation like this:

```
{% if not form.field.vars.valid %}
     <span style='color: red;'>{{ form_label(form.field) }}</span>
{% else %}
    {{ form_label(form.field) }}
{% endif %}
```

The case is that form.field.vars.valid is always valid even when there are errors.
I know form validation is working because I debbuged and seen there where errors reported to the form. Also, after submiting the form, Symfony correctly renders the red border around the field when it has focus. But I want to provide a more clear visual reference to the user. 
I also tried this with form.field.vars.errors|length > 0 and but it always return zero length even with the errors.

I seen some references to error_bubblig and I have tried to enable/disable it both for form and for specific fields in the form class and it didn't have any effects on form.field.vars.valid or form.field.vars.errors|length.

My project used Symfony 2.3.6 and in order to solve this I upgraded to 2.3.22, then do 2.6 and the problem persists.

Any help apreciated. Thanks

Also can someone can point me to error_bubbling documentation/examples ? Searching for this problem I've seen some references to it, but could't find a good explanation to it.

Comment: Edited the answer in order to make it more clear. Hope it's better this time.

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented similar for my previous project. I've used `formBooking.vars.valid` and it returns `1` or `empty string`. And here is some form snippet to show you how I've used `error|length`:

```
    <div class="form-group col-lg-4">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 {{ form.field.vars.errors|length > 0 ? 'has-error' }}">
                <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>&nbsp;{{ form_label(form.field, 'Some Label') }}
                {{ form_widget(form.field, {'attr': {'class': 'datepicker form-control', 'placeholder':'Some label'}}) }}
            </div>
            {{ form_errors(form.field, {'attr': {'class': 'error'}}) }}
        </div>
    </div>
```

Basically, I've wrapped the widget with a div and add `has-error` class if field has error, then with css I style it the way I want. `form_error` could be placed where ever you want, I've decided to place it below the `form_widget`. Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes... that's similar to what I want. But what's happening in my case is that form.field.vars.errors|length equals 0 even when form has errors. So it breaks this. Any idea why ?

Comment: is it en embedded form? because I have same issue but with embedded form.

Comment: Yes it is... so there is a bug ? any workarounds ?

Comment: What I did was to create `Custom Validator` and throw error general error for entire embedded form. The thing was that I did not want to enter new data from embedded form, I was just selecting existing embedded entities and adding it to parent entity.